# PostMan GET works, but RestSharp returns empty JSON result

Tags: c#, restsharp, postman, jira-rest-api

Im trying to figure out why my PostMan GET works fine, but when i do the same command through Visual Studio, i get an empty JSON.

RestSharp GET

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {         

        var client = new RestClient("http://ignitemedia.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/");
        var request = new RestRequest("project/", Method.GET);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

        return null;
    }
```

POSTMan GET

```
http://ignitemedia.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project
no Headers
```

Comment: POSTMan also returns an empty JSON when ran on http://ignitemedia.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project , did you mean http://ignitemedia.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project/10051 like your C# example? And are you sure whatever URL you mean to run it on is correct? This won't return an IEnumerable<string>, and you're only ever returning null, if you mean to use it outside you need to fix the return types AND the return.

Comment: yes, i got rid of the project ID, and i will change the return type once i can get it to actually populate. thats strange, when i do a get on the URL, POSTMan returns a list of projects. Is there some sort of credentials cached somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing it was missing was an "s" in "https".

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. For me, it was an issue getting the request past the proxy. Adding this to the config file solved the issue:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
  <proxy autoDetect="False" bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="proxy domain address" usesystemdefault="False" />
</defaultProxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

SSl issue in some places
Place the below code in the method

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).